# Visual Studio 2022 reverts options / settings to default on its own

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I have experienced this problem multiple times. Visual Studio would revert settings back to defaults. Anyone know why this happens?

Specific settings that I've been trying to change are one of the shortcuts for ReSharper and source control default folder.
I setup Visual Studio only about a month ago. This would happen seemingly randomly when I open VS (happened twice in the last month). It is not the subsequent opening of VS and VS never crashed in these instances. The computer was never forced to restart or shut down. Also, VS was not updated. The computer is new and VS was only setup 1 month ago. Also, I used to think it was an issue of integration with ReSharper, but VS also reverted the source control folder, which has nothing to do with ReSharper.

I can't find this question being asked. Perhaps anyone knows something that would trigger VS to revert options that I selected previously?
The only reason I can think of so far, is if every time a new update is added for VS, it changes settings for everyone back to default. This seems absurd, so unlikely. It also seems that this happens more often with VS 2022 than VS 2019 (from my past experiments with both running). Currently I only have VS 2022 installed.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is really late, but just so you know you're not crazy, this has been happening to me as well.  It's really difficult to search for an answer because the results are all for intentionally resetting your settings.  If I find the answer, I'll reply here.  If you have found an answer, please reply.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35268706)